# Convert a integer or a character to a corresponding enum

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game using OOP C++.
I have a enum for pieces like:

```
enum class Type : uint8_t
{
    O,
    X,
    None
};
```

I have also a class player and here have this function:

```
Piece Player::PickPiece(std::istream& in) const
{
    in >> pickedPiece;
    in >> temp;
    auto pickedPiece = static_cast<Piece::Type>(temp);
    return pickedPiece;
}
```

It works only when I read values like 0 for O (zero for O), 1 for X, but I want to read a char like X or O and then convert it to the int enum. How can I do this? I know I can do it with some if conditiosn but i don't like this method.

Comment: Have you tried `if (temp == 'X' || temp == 'x') return Type::X;` ?

Comment: The title says "convert enum to int", but it seems like you actually want to convert a string to an enum. Which is it?

Comment: "Convert a enum to a int in C++" -  Use a cast: `int int_value_of_enum = static_cast<int>(an_enum_value);`

Comment: `enum class Type` - that's a *very* generic name you've got there. You may want to re-think that :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a switch statement:

```
Piece convert(int value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 0:
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            return Piece::O;
        case 1:
        case 'x':
        case 'X':
            return Piece::X;
        default:
            // Handle the case when the character and the integers are wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to do `switch (tolower(value))` instead of checking both lowercase and uppercase letter for each character on each statement...?

Comment: That's a good point. I don't want to, just in case there are some other integers than just 0 and 1 (not here, but if someone else looks at the solution) and one of them gets converted.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned your enum types will be equivalent to `0, 1 and 2`. You can however give your enums distinct values in the declaration.

```
enum class Type : uint8_t
{
    O = 'O',
    X = 'X',
    None
};

Type t = static_cast<Type>('X');
```

You can however no longer use 0 and 1. Another thing to note is that if you use specifically use `char`s you should probably use that as your underlying type instead of `uint8_t` as they are not guaranteed to be the same.